# Plotting a graph with different marker colors based on attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a df that looks like this:

|  | latitude | longitude | cod_postal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40.244350 | -8.443650 | 3025-151 |
| 2 | 40.626130 | -8.645250 | 3810-419 |
| 1 | 40.626130 | -8.645250 | 3810-498 |
| 3 | 40.626130 | -8.645250 | 3810-419 |

I want to plot a graph with the lat and lon coordinates (a line plot) where the marker face color is different based on the cod_postal label.

I have come up with this:

```
color_labels=df['cod_postal'].unique()
    
#list of rgb
rgb_values=sns.color_palette('Set2', 8)

#Assign label to a rgb code
color_map=dict(zip(color_labels, rgb_values))

plt.plot(df['latitude'], df['longitude'], marker='o', mfc=df['cod_postal'].map(color_map))
```

But I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4
```

How can I fix this?
I know that if I was plotting a scatter it would work, but for my case, being a line plot is essential.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Adding a reference picture for my expected output.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot()` is expecting a single color for the `mfc` parameter.

Using `marker="o"`, it looks like you're trying to create a scatter plot. If it's the case, you should use `plt.scatter`. You can now pass multiple colors to the `c=` parameter (one for each scatter point).

```py
color_labels=df['cod_postal'].unique()
    
#list of rgb
rgb_values=sns.color_palette('Set2', 8)

#Assign label to a rgb code
color_map=dict(zip(color_labels, rgb_values))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Create scatter plot, with one color 'cod_postal'
plt.scatter(df['latitude'], df['longitude'], c=df['cod_postal'].map(color_map).values)
```

[image]

*items 1, 2, and 3 have the same coordinates so they overlap on the figure.*

---

*Edit regarding the reference image provided.*

I would then suggest you to do that in 2 steps. First create the scatter plot as explained above. Then create a line plot for the connecting black line.

```py
plt.scatter(df['latitude'], df['longitude'], c=df['cod_postal'].map(color_map).values, zorder=3) 
plt.plot(df['latitude'], df['longitude'], c="k")
```

I adjusted the dataframe to make the figure a bit more interesting

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [40.244350, -8.443650, "3025-151"],
    [41.244350, -9.443650, "3025-151"],
    [42.244350, -8.443650, "3025-151"],
    [40.626130, -8.645250, "3810-419"],
    [41.626130, -8.645250, "3810-419"],
], columns=["latitude", "longitude", "cod_postal"])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! but I'm not trying to plot a scatter plot. I need the line connecting the points, I added a picture of the expected output for reference.

Comment: Ok ! To reproduce the reference image, you'll have to do a scatter plot followed by a line plot. I've updated the answer.